# How many different ways are there to place a white and a black rook on a chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways are there to place a white and a black tower on a chessboard so that they
a) attack each other?
b) do not attack each other?
c) What would be the solution of a) and b) if the two rooks were black?

Comment: By "tower" you mean [rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) (= Tauer in German), right?

Comment: it depends on what's considered a different way. Is a board that is equivalent to another board rotated distinct? what if it's reflected? etc.

Answer (score 2):

a) There are 28 edge locations. For each edge location there are $7 \times 7$ ways to place the opposing rook such that it does not attack the other.

There are 36 non-edge locations. If a rook is placed on the square $(a,c)$ (I'm not using the proper chess notation of $F8$ or $G4$) for $a, c \in \{2, 3, ... , 6, 7\}$ think about how many ways there are to place the other rook:

Four rectangles of size $(a-1) \times (b-1), (a-1) \times (8-b),  (8-a) \times (b-1), (8-a) \times (8-b).$

This is 
$$(ab  -a -b +1) + (8a -ab -8 + b) + (8b - 8 - ab + a) + (64 - 8b - 8a + ab)$$ 
Cancel the $ab$ terms
$$ =(-a -b +1) + (8a -8 + b) + (8b - 8  + a) + (64 - 8b - 8a )$$ 
Cancel the $a$ and $b$ terms
$$ =1 + -8 - 8  + 64 = 49 = 7 \times 7.$$

Evidently the number of available spaces doesn't change based on whether or not you are on the edge (this is easily seen by just visualizing a rook on the board).

So there are $64 \times 49$ ways.

b) Just take the total number of combinations: $64 \times 63 - 64 \times 49 = 64 \times 14$ (again as expected).

c) How would this change the problem?

Comment: You have parts a and b backwards.

Comment: All that algebra to prove that a rook on any square attacks 14 squares, 7 on its rank and 7 on its file?